# Get user IP address with JSF API without the need for Servlet API

Tags: jsf-2, ip-address

I get some user data through a simple form. When dealing with the data in the corresponding backing bean's action method, I am currently getting the IP address of a user this way:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String ipAddress = request.getHeader( "X-FORWARDED-FOR" );
if ( ipAddress == null ) {
    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Is there another way, a more "JSF" way, where I wouldn't need to hook on `HttpServletRequest`? I read many times that having to use `javax.servlet.*` in a `@ManagedBean` is not a good design, but I couldn't find anything else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there isn't. The [`ExternalContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) doesn't have a method which delegates to [`ServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29).

Your best bet is to hide it away in an utlity method. The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has among many other helpful methods exactly this method in the [`Faces`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html) utility class: [`Faces#getRemoteAddr()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) which also takes forwarded address into account.

The [source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.java) is here:

```
/**
 * Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client that sent the request. This will first check the
 * <code>X-Forwarded-For</code> request header and if it's present, then return its first IP address, else just
 * return {@link HttpServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()} unmodified.
 * @return The IP address of the client.
 * @see HttpServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()
 * @since 1.2
 */
public static String getRemoteAddr() {
    String forwardedFor = getRequestHeader("X-Forwarded-For");

    if (!Utils.isEmpty(forwardedFor)) {
        return forwardedFor.split("\\s*,\\s*", 2)[0]; // It's a comma separated string: client,proxy1,proxy2,...
    }

    return getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Note that `X-Forwarded-For` header represents a commaseparated string and that your own code didn't take that into account.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and thanks for the reminder of OmniFaces! I took a look at it last time I saw an update on your blog, but I didn't think it would address this issue.